# Sort unanswered questions within my tags by date?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I select the "my tags" option under Unanswered questions, they are sorted by upvotes. I would like to sort them **by date**. Yet, this seems to be no possible.

If it is actually not possible, why is this so? It seems unnatural to me to be prompted with questions asked two years ago, some of which are no longer relevant (e.g. EOL). Actually, if there is an **optimal** way I can contribute to the network, it is by having quick access to new question on topics which I feel comfortable.

Comment: This may be good enough: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110782/249827.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about it. I really like the AU environment and cheerful colours :). I'm not sure I want to move to that ugly SE platform. I understand people using it if they come from other equally ugly networks like tex or unix.  In any case, I think it would be a very simple thing to implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are somewhat able to this at the moment with the advanced search functionality (Well you only sort by newest). If you search for `intags:mine is:question isanswered:no hasaccepted:no closed:no` in the search box at the top right, you would get get the same result as you would if you clicked the [Unanswered](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) tab.

But in this case, since this is a search result, you would be able to sort by any of these 4 options:

- relevance
- newest
- votes
- active

This is a direct link to the search result on the main site and sorted by date:
https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion%20isanswered%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3ano

*P.S. You need both `isanswered:no` and `hasaccepted:no` to correctly filter them and have the same result as the Unanswered tab. As questions with an accepted answer but with a vote of 1 or less, is not being considered as answered in the search results. But it is considered answered in the Unanswered tab.*